# Yammer Integration with intranet application

Tags: yammer

I am trying to integrate Yammer with our company platform which can be accessed only under intranet. While trying it, I am getting error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource". Can anyone help me how can my intranet app share resources with Yammer. What should be the link has to be given under Javascript Origin in Yammer Client Applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of `JavaScript Origin` to "localhost" while creating an application in Yammer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the local atom, then use it.

Comment: I am not using localhost, using our company platform. It is working fine with localhost. Now I would like to integrate with this platform which can only be accessed with intranet.